# Laravel 5.1 csv to array hashing password

Tags: arrays, csv, laravel, hash, import

I have a `CSV` file with a couple of hundred user. Every user has a unique code.
When uploading the csv it will create an array with user information

Example:

```
    array(
      "name"          => "Test person1",
      "uniqueCode"    => "5987E2f",
      "email"         => "testperson1@gmail.com",
      "officenr"      => "2.12"
      "authID"        => 2 (normal user)
)
```

When creating this array there will be a check to determine if the user exists in the db by looking at uniqueCode. If it exists don't import the user else import it into the db

For importing into the db the uniqueCode will be hashed with

```
$password = Hash::make($request->uniqueCode)
```

and would be place into the password field.

But when the array has a couple of hundred user and all the uniqueCode's needs to be hashed it takes up to 15 sec.

Is there a way to do this different.

Comment: Surely if the uniqueCode is unique you could just insert that and test for the existence of the uniqueCode? If it's actually the password and will later be used for login, what about users with the same password? Their user wouldn't be created. If it's not actually the password and you really want to hash something use a faster hashing algorithm like md5. If it is indeed a password stick to the stronger, slower alogrithm

Comment: The uniqueCode is always unique. So when importing the users for the firsttime i was thinking to set there password with there uniqueCode. Every person knows there unique code so they could login with it and then change it to another one. But the hash proces takes to many time

Comment: If you're generating accounts which users can log into then you'll need to hash something. You could perhaps store the unique code in another column, and create a job in a queue which later generates the hash from the unique column. That way you wont waste time making hashes for existing users to test against and the overall process would be quick. Your queue worker/job could then notify the user by email when their account was ready, i.e. the hash for their password had been made.

Comment: So what you saying is when importing the array with the users the password field would become plain text with the uniqueCode. And later on a queue job makes all these fields hashed.

Comment: Actually, ideally you'd want to pass the unique code to the job with the user ID and store a fast hash of that in the database. Use the fast hash to see if it's a new user without actually storing the unique code in the database. That way the unique code isn't ever in plain text in your persistent store

Comment: If i use a fast hash like sha1 all the users are imported in the db within a couple of mil sec. But is there a way to refecter the sha1 pass to laravel hash pash (this needs to be done in a queue job)

Comment: No you can't recover the hash. You'd need to either store the unique code with the user and have a job retrieve that, or pass the unique code to the queue as part of the data.